# How to install Oracle express 10g and forms builder on windows 8.1

Tags: oracle10g, formbuilder

I have a project for databases course and need oracle 10g to create tables using sql+ and then build forms using form builder. I've tried many ways to install oracle express 10g and form builder but can't find the right way.

Comment: What's the error?  You know that 10g isn't supported any longer and was never tested to install (or work) on Windows 8, right?  Why are you trying to use obsolete software on a brand-new operating system?  That's generally a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @JustinCave There's no error because I couldn't find anything useful. I'm trying this because the lab in my campus uses the same version and maybe it'll not be compatible.

Comment: @JustinCave I've tried to install now and got the error: "The value of the environment path is longer than 1023 characters. This value can't be set".